# Why am I getting a horizontal scrollbar on the page

Tags: css

I've tried so many things on this page

https://boycottplus.org/campaign/reclaim-our-time-say-no-time-wasting-websites

On the right column, I can't get a padding or margin of 10px between it and the left column without a scroll bar appearing.  I've tried using a wrapper div but everything I do seems to bring the scroll bar :-/

The style I am focusing on

```
.subsection .inner {
padding-left: 10px;
}
```

in firefox

Comment: I don't see the horizontal scrollbar. It displays normally for me (Firefox).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `overflow:hidden` to your `body` style.

Answer (score 1):

Are you setting `width` and `padding` on the same element?

For example, if you have:

```
.subsection .inner {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

then the total width of the inner div will be 100% + 10px, which will result in a scroll bar.

Comment: Of course, that situation only arises because the browser is calculating the box's size based off of the content-box. If you set `box-sizing: border-box`, then width: 100% actually means 100% while taking padding in to consideration.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove scrollbar in horizontal direction, then use **overflow-x:** hidden; in that particular HTML element, keeping your vertical scrollbar intact.